# Excel International Date Format

Tags: excel, vba

I am using this VBA line to set the date in a cell.

```
sheet1.Range("A1").Value = CDate(Format(Now(), "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm"))
```

Will this work with all different languages of Excel? I have been experimenting with a lot of different options and found problems between foreign versions of Excel. Basically I have the same spreadsheet that will be moving around different countries and everything needs to remain functional.

I will be doing `date additions/subtractions` as well as `time additions/subtractions` on the cells that this vba line is used.

From my research `yyyy-mm-dd` is the international date format? Please confirm.

Comment: from what research? `yyyy-mm-dd` seems to be part of [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard, and I haven't seen `yyyy-dd-mm` in practical use anywhere.. if you need to use Excel for date operations, do you want to store the dates as numbers or as text in excel spreadsheet?

Comment: I want to store them as dates, the sheet will be hidden from users so i don't mind if the formatting looks ugly as long as it works. I have had real issues moving between english / Greek systems.

Comment: there is no `date` data type in an Excel Spreadsheet - only number or text. all date formatting is just about that, formatting of a number, nothing about different data types

Answer (score 1):

This will work in all different languages, although if you just use `Sheet1.Range("A2").Value = Now` the effect will be the same. The cell will be formatted with the Excel default. On my machine this resulted in

```
15/09/2014 10:09
```

The value is a real date and can be used in calculations. Problems with date formats often arise in VBA when a specific format is generated with, or expected by, a VBA command.

Comment: teylyn, I think I have tried just 'Now' on a machine with Greek System and the result was not as expected. Thanks for testing.

Comment: To give you an example, the user will be setting a date in the Greek system and then send the spreadsheet to US. The spreadsheet will add a US date and needs to be able to subtract it from the first Greek Date.. This doesn't work if I just use NOW

Comment: What do you get on a Greek systems with `Now`? How do you subtract the dates? If you let Excel do the work in spreadsheet cells instead of using VBA, then all should be fine.